# Split text after X words for read more function

Tags: jquery

I need a function that wraps html (text) into 2 divs after X words. I now have some JS that doesn't work very well. Need something simpler. One of the problems is that it splits somewhere inside a `<p>` and does not wrap the next text into a `<p>`.

```
// Function to split text and add read more

(function($) {

    $.fn.splitWords = function(index) {

        return this.each(function() {

            var el = $(this),
                i, first, words = el.html().split(/\s/);


            if (typeof index === 'number') {
                i = (index > 0) ? index : words.length + index;
            }
            else {
                i = Math.floor(words.length / 2);
            }

            first = words.splice(0, i);

            el.empty().
                append(makeWrapElem(1, first)).
                append(makeWrapElem(2, words));
        });
    };

    function makeWrapElem(i, wordList) {
        return $('<div class="px-text-wrap-' + i + '">' + wordList.join(' ') + ' </div>');
    }

}(jQuery));
```

The function executes as following:

```
$('.my-text').splitWords(40);
```

See this fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/tucjkwar/1/

Problem is sometimes it adds 2 classes of "px-text-wrap-2" somehow. I'd like the function to be simpler.

Comment: Your first (obvious) issue is `el.html().` - this will, as the name suggests, give you the *html* - so if you have `<span class='c1 c2'>` you get `[ "<span", "class='", "c1", "c2'>"]` which makes no sense.  You either need to parse the HTML which is substantially more complex or use `el.text()`   As you've not provided a sample before/after, it's hard to tell your intent.

Comment: *does not wrap the next text* - I'm guess this is referring to `tellus.</p><p>Consectetur` - your `.split` is only on whitespace, there's no whitespace there, so your code thinks it's a single word.

Comment: Or take an alternative approach, eg with a div with css `overflow:hidden` then make the div larger on "show more".  Maybe use `text-overflow: ellipsis;`